# Python: shared methods and attributes in multiple inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I simply want to create a class which inherits attributes and methods from two parents. Let's just say the two parent classes are

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def method_a(self):
        return self.a + 10


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

    def method_b(self):
        return self.b + 20
```

Then I am not sure how to create a subclass C which inherits both methods and attributes from its parents. I can do something like this, but I am quite sure this is not very pythonic...

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        A.__init__(self, a=a)
        B.__init__(self, b=b)
```

then I can do this without a problem

```
my_class = C(a=1, b=2)
print(my_class.a)
print(my_class.b)
print(my_class.method_a())
print(my_class.method_b())
```

I don't know how to set up `super` to inherit methods and attributes from both parents and I would appreciate any help! And by the way: Classes A and B should not depend on each other.

Comment: Such information can be easily found with a quick Google search.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the way `super` works is that, based on the list of superclasses declared at the beginning of the subclass, an `mro` (method resolution order) list will be worked out. When you call `supper` (Python 3), the `__init__` of the first class in the `mro` list will be called. That `__init__` is also expected to contain another `super()` so that the `__init__` of the next class in the `mro` also gets called.

In your case, the `mro` list should be `[A, B]`. So the `__init__` of `A` must contain an invocation of `super` so that the `__init__` of `B` is also get called.

The problems here are:

- You want `A` and `B` not to depend of each other. The use of `super` needs an `mro` list, which does not satisfy this requirement as I explained above.
- The `__init__` of `C` has 2 parameters while those of `A` and `B` have only 1. You may be able to pass `a` to `A` but I don't know if there's a way for you to pass `b` to `B`.

So it seems to me that `super` cannot help in this situation.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. I just left the explicit constructor calls as they are defined above in the original post. Seems to work nicely!